# Why my event handler is not called

Tags: javascript, extjs

I´m using ExtJs4.1, here is my example. The "calendarioChange" is not called in this way:

```
Ext.define('App.view.atendimento.Agenda', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window', 
  maximized: true,
  bodyPadding: 4,
  constrain: true,
  layout: 'hbox',
  items:[
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        width: 300,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                handler: this.calendarioChange
            }
        ]
    }
  ],
  calendarioChange: function(picker, date){
    alert('changed');
  }
});
```

but in thsi way works:

```
 xtype: 'datepicker',
     handler: function(picker, date){
                   alert('changed');
              }
```

What I´m missing in the first case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you haven't taken in account the scope of your handle. Every time you nest a {} constructor you change the 'this' pointer. In your case:

```
this.calendarioChange
```

Can not work because 'this' is pointing to the datepicker not the Window. You could solve it by adding a function in the event that locate the window and then call to the appropiate method:

```
items: [
            {
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                handler: function(picker, date) {
                    var window = this.up('window');
                    window.calendarioChange(picker, date);
                }
            }
...
```

Comment: Yes it is, but it is not the preferred solution for bigger applications. Could be more elegant using the Sencha MVC because that behavior will be implemented in the controller and in this case you  haven't nested objects

Answer (score 0):

Because the method you define as an event handler is not in `this` scope. For example you can declare the method outside `Ext.define()` call and then refer it just by name.